# data or datasets field are required to render char bar in angular 4

Tags: angular, charts

I am trying to use ng2-charts in my angular 4 project

HTML:

```
 <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="customerBarChartData"
            [colors]="barChartColors"
            [options]="customerBarChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            ></canvas>
```

TS:

```
  geochatArry: Array<any> = [];
  ....
  public customerBarChartData:any[] = this.geochatArry;
  .... 
  /// Service
   this.geochatArry=data.json();
   console.log(this.geochatArry);
```

[image]

but i am getting `ng-charts configuration error,data or datasets field are required to render char bar`. Kindly tell me where is my mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to create the chart after you have received your data.

When you've built your chart, assign a variable like

`chartReady = true;`

In your `HTML`, wrap the chart with a

`*ngIf="chartReady"`

so you can hide it until you have build your chart.

Answer (score 13):

Use *ngIf when the dynamic data comes in "customerBarChartData" array then it will work.

```
<div style="display: block" *ngIf="customerBarChartData">
   <canvas baseChart
   [datasets]="customerBarChartData"
   [colors]="barChartColors"
   [options]="customerBarChartOptions"
   [legend]="barChartLegend"
   [chartType]="barChartType">
</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to customerBarChartData, which is initialized to empty because geochatArry is empty. When you later set geochatArry, you aren't setting customerBarChartData like you think you are.

Add console.log( this.customerBarChartData ) for verification.